# TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'jasmineEnv.executeFiltered()')

Tags: jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

When running Jasmine unit tests with karma, karma spits the following out into the console:

```
INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Linux)]: Connected on socket Tbp5etNZBA7QCK_cBaJL with id 89324857
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Linux) ERROR
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'jasmineEnv.executeFiltered()')
at /home/thalley887/Documents/Projects/DashboardAngular/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js:171
```

Here are the list of files I've included in my Karma.conf.js:

```
files: [
    'test/lib/jasmine-*/jasmine.js',
    'test/lib/jasmine-*/jasmine-html.js',
    'test/lib/jasmine-*/*.js',
    'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
    'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
    'bower_components/angular-*/*.js',
    'app/scripts/app.js',
    'app/scripts/**/*.js',
    'test/spec/*.js'
],
```

I have one spec file. I suspect I am missing a file in the files: [] array or I have the order I'm loading the javascript files wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should remove jasmine from the `files` array, Karma already comes with a version of Jasmine. You probably have a newer version of Jasmine, and it confuses Karma.